# What classes of scripture are claimed to be apaurusheya?

Tags: scripture, vedas, upanishads, brahmanas, classification

It is well known that Vedas are claimed to be *apaurusheya* or not of human origin. Hindu scripture has been continuously produced since the Veda-Samhitas – Brahmanas, Aranyakas, Upanishads, Itihasas, Puranas and so forth. There are also a lot of sectarian works which would be considered scripture by adherents of the sect.

Has anything been written in scriptures to recognize the *lakshanas* of *apaurusheya* works?

Comment: upanishad, brahmana, aranyaka are all part of the veda. Veda is not just Rk.

Comment: Only the śruti (i.e. Veda) is considered to be aupauruṣeya in Vedānta and Pūrva Mīmāṁsā schools. The śruti comprises of Veda, which includes the Saṁhitās, Brāhmaṇas, Āraṇyakas and Upaniṣads.
However, some sectarian  beliefs now may wrongly project some smr̥tis as aupauruṣeya. For eg. some orthodox believers of Gauḍīya Vaiṣṇavas have the view that Bhagavad Gītā is aupauruṣeya, but that's not true because Bhagavad Gita (BG) is a portion of Mahābhārata which is smr̥ti, it's written by human author/authors. None of the itihāsa texts and other except the Veda hold that status of being called śruti